# Pandas add unique count column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
            'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
     'B' : [2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2]})
df

    A       B
0   foo     2
1   foo     4
2   foo     4
3   foo     2
4   bar     5
5   bar     4
6   bar     3
7   bar     2
```

I would like a column ('C') of the count of unique values for 'B' per group of 'A' like this via a lambda x function:

```
    A       B    C
0   foo     2    2
1   foo     4    2
2   foo     4    2
3   foo     2    2
4   bar     5    1
5   bar     4    1
6   bar     3    1
7   bar     2    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get 1 unique value for B for the "bar" group?

Comment: @DSM, I thought the same, I think it is the count of each element per group, two 2's and two 4's in the first and one 5 one 4 etc.. in the next. Like `df.groupby("A")["B"].value_counts()`

Answer (score 4):

If PC is right about your goal, maybe

```
>>> df["C"] = df.groupby(["A","B"])["A"].transform("count")
>>> df
     A  B  C
0  foo  2  2
1  foo  4  2
2  foo  4  2
3  foo  2  2
4  bar  5  1
5  bar  4  1
6  bar  3  1
7  bar  2  1
```

would give you what you want?  We're grouping on (A,B) pairs.

---

Cute bit of history: this is originally what I'd done, but then I tried it again and found I didn't need the `["A"]`.  But the reason it worked the second time without it is that I had the `C` column then, so there was something for the code to act on.. (sigh)

Comment: I think you nailed it.

Comment: I had to `df["C"] = df.groupby(["A","B"])["A"].transform("count")` to avoid a `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: aargh, I know why.  I'll put it back.