# matrix representation of pandas data-frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, pivot, dataframe

i have a data-frame like

```
 from   to  Amt
 a      b   100
 a      c   200
 a      d   220
 b      a   250
 b      c   300
 b      d   330
 c      a   100
 c      b   120
 c      d   320
 d      a   211
 d      b   980
 d      c   430
```

i want to represent it in matrix format like

```
     a     b     c    d
a    0    100    200  220
b   250    0     300  330
c   100   120    0    320
d   211   980    430   0
```

How to achieve that..

i have followed [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data) link.But not getting what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pivot your data. Here is an example.

```
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='from', columns='to', values='Amt')
```

For doing fractional calculations before hand, you might use `groupby()` then `transform('sum')`. It is similar to a SQL window function sum.

```
df['sums'] =  df.groupby('from')['amt'].transform('sum')
df['frac'] = df['amt'] / df['sums']
df.pivot(index='from', columns='to', values='frac')
```

Comment: @David-in place of values='Amt' can i pass some o/p of a function.  Actually i need to pass the % of Amt field for each from to corresponding to.

Comment: You would probably want to first precompute the value before pivoting. Let me see... I remember a really clever way of doing window functions on a dataframe. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Added a way to calculate the `amt / sum(amt over all from)` . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457982/pandas-add-unique-count-column/34458096#34458096

Answer (score 3):

You need to pivot the data frame.  See
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

```
df.pivot(index="from", columns="to",values="Amt" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve that with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df_pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, index='from', columns='to', fill_value=0)
print(df_pivoted)

      Amt               
to      a    b    c    d
from                    
a       0  100  200  220
b     250    0  300  330
c     100  120    0  320
d     211  980  430    0
```