# Add column with accumulative count of unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column with the number of unique values appearances, so if my input is:

```
id  |  score
 asd    15
 asd    20
 jk     76
 pz     54
 pz     37
```

I want to add a column like this

```
 id  | score  | count_ids
 asd    15           1
 asd    20           1
 jk     76           2
 pz     54           3
 pz     37           3
```

I've seen this answer [Pandas add unique count column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457982/pandas-add-unique-count-column), although I feel like there should be a neater solution to this.

> Edit

I'm also looking for a scalable solution, so for example, if I also have this:

```
 id  |  game  |  score
 asd    1          15
 asd    2          20
 jk     1          76
 pz     1          54
 pz     1          37
```

Get

```
 id  |  game  |  score  | count_users
 asd    1          15         1
 asd    2          20         2
 jk     1          76         3
 pz     1          54         4
 pz     1          37         4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think solution should be simplify without helper column:

```
df['count_ids'] = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df)
    id  score  count_ids
0  asd     15          1
1  asd     20          1
2   jk     76          2
3   pz     54          3
4   pz     37          3
```

EDIT: For multiple columns solution is similar, only add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per row:

```
df['count_ids'] = df[['id', 'game']].ne(df[['id', 'game']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
print (df)

    id  game  score  count_ids
0  asd     1     15          1
1  asd     2     20          2
2   jk     1     76          3
3   pz     1     54          4
4   pz     1     37          4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[['id', 'game']].ne(df[['id', 'game']].shift()))
      id   game
0   True   True
1  False   True
2   True   True
3   True  False
4  False  False
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. I posted a simplification of my problem because I thought that would be enough, but apparently it wasn't sorry about that.
So, how could I use this in order to use it with more than one column? (See my edit)

Comment: Thank you very much! You were very helpful and nice!